# Unison's "ignorenot" parameter does not work

Tags: unison

I have the following instruction in my unison profile:

```
ignore = Path node_modules
ignorenot = Path node_modules/scaffold
```

Easy enough, right? Except that it doesn't work. It keeps on ignoring the `node_modules/scaffold` folder.

I even tried it with a regex:

```
ignorenot = Regex /node_modules/scaffold/.*
```

So what's going on here? I'm running unison 2.48.4

Comment: I think this quote from the [Unison manual](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html) addresses what's going wrong here: "*Note that the semantics of `ignore` and `ignorenot` is a little counter-intuitive. When detecting updates, Unison examines paths in depth-first order, starting from the roots of the replicas and working downwards. Before examining each path, it checks whether it matches `ignore` and does not match `ignorenot`;...*

Comment: *... in this case it skips this path and all its descendants. This means that, if some parent of a given path matches an `ignore` pattern, then it will be skipped even if the path itself matches an `ignorenot` pattern. In particular, putting `ignore = Path *` in your profile and then using `ignorenot` to select particular paths to be synchronized will not work. Instead, you should use the `path` preference to choose particular paths to synchronize.*"

Comment: Oh, that explains it. When I change the `ignore` to `ignore = Path node_modules/*`, the ignorenot DOES work.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, when you `ignore` a directory, there is *no way* to un-ignore a descendant.

What you should do instead is ignore the directory's contents, and then un-ignore a specific child. This will work for example:

```
ignore = Path node_modules/*
ignorenot = Path node_modules/scaffold
```